# PHP Flush doesn't work properly with HTML table

Tags: php, internet-explorer, html-table, flush

I have a problem with `flush()` and a HTML table using "Internet Explorer".
I edited the following code to display a "real time" echo in a table with `flush()`, I put the `flush()` call after the `</table>` tag because in "Internet Explorer" it doesn't work, but I don't know why only the first echo of my cycle goes into the table, the others go outside. Any help?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<table border='1'>
<tr>
<td>

<?php

 $total = 10;

 for($i=1; $i<=$total; $i++){

 echo "sometext";

 //other stuff

    ?>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php
echo str_repeat(' ',1024*64);

flush();
    sleep(1);

}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you meaning to close the `<table>` on every single iteration?

Answer (score 0):

You are closing your table inside of your loop.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table border='1'>
<tr>
<td>

<?php

 $total = 10;

 for($i=1; $i<=$total; $i++){

 echo "sometext";

 //other stuff

  echo str_repeat(' ',1024*64);

  flush();
  sleep(1);
}

?>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Proof: [image]

Comment: i try also this solution, but if you try with internet explorer all the echo is displayed at the end of the script.

Comment: Probably because you never open your <body> tag. See my edit. With the <body> tag it works on my machine.

Comment: you try with internet explorer too?
i try your edit but in internet explorer 9 the flush work, but only first echo goes into table cell

Comment: Unfortunately I only have IE10 on Win7, but it definitely works, the table cell slowly grows with one "sometext" each second, all in the same cell, not below the table. See my edit for screenshot.

Comment: so i think it's IE9 the problem, because my output show only at the end of the execution. what a strange thing...

Comment: If you want your page to slowly refresh/fill with data coming from a script on your server, AJAX would be better idea, the page could itself poll your server every few seconds to fetch new data and add it to the page. That would work on all browsers...

Comment: Sure: http://jsfiddle.net/yz4RC/1/   Pleaee note that `fakeData` is only for demonstration purposes on jsFiddle.org, you can remove it for your stuff. Anything your server returns will be appended to the `live_content` div.

Answer (score 0):

Put simply, you've closed the table inside the loop rather than outside of the loop. So after the first iteration, your table tags don't match up. Move `</table>` beyond your closing loop curly bracket `}`.

Concerning the Internet Explorer problem. You may want to look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php

It talks about some versions of Internet Explorer requiring a certain amount of bytes before it will begin to flush data. You may also want to try calling `ob_flush();` above your `flush();` statement.

Comment: if i put `</table>` after loop closing, with internet explorer the output is displayed at the end of all iteration and no step by step.

Comment: @user1825932 Interesting. Which version of Internet Explorer is that?

Comment: @user1825932 You may want to read this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php

It mentions problems with Internet Explorer needing a certain amount of bytes before it can begin to flush; also try calling `ob_flush();` just about `flush();`.

Comment: i try to use `ob_flush();` just above my flush without success.
I use `echo str_repeat(' ',1024*64) ` to obtain the necessary bytes to flush

Comment: yes :) without the `str_repeat` the output show at the end of the script.

Comment: @user1825932 Good to hear.

Comment: the problem is internet explorer. I use javascript to avoid the problem.
now i edit the first post with my solution :)

Answer (score 0):

The browser might be waiting for the closing  because it does not know the content of all cells, and thus also the width of the columns. Try to hint it with fixed values for the td element, for example:

```
<td style="width: 200px">
```

Comment: doesn't work.
It creates a cell with 200px width but the output is the same, the first echo in the cell, the other outside.